# Passing data from AWS lambda to API gateway

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is is possible to pass streaming kinesis data from an AWS Lambda to an ApiGateway? I want to populate the stream that the lambda is receiving and populate it to the frontend, and I haven't seen much documentation on this.

Comment: Are you trying to work with Kinesis data from a Spring app?

Comment: @smac2020 Yes. I am programmatically creating, and putting the data into a stream. The streams are connected to a lambda, but I can't seem to export the data from the lambda with an api gateway. I'm assuming this is possible?

Comment: If you are developing a Spring app, then why not use the AWS SDK for Java V2 (preferability) and perform Kinesis operations directly via the API. That is, build some Spring services that can perform AWS Service operations directly as opposed to using Lambda and Gateway.

Comment: @smac2020 That's what I'm doing to create and add records to the stream, but I'm not sure how to use this so I can access the stream from the frontend (GET request)

Comment: To do this, you need to read the Kinesis data stream using the Java API, then use Spring APIs to stream that data. There are some online discussions that talk about this use case. For example -- https://dzone.com/articles/streaming-data-with-spring-boot-restful-web-servic.

Comment: @smac2020 Ok. I'll take a look into this. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great use case - we have added this to a list for end to end discussions.

Comment: Excellent, that should be most helpful!